# Create a copy on demand

Tags: c++, c++20

Is there an idiomatic way to invoke the creation of a copy in an expression?

For example say I have a function declared as:

```cpp
template <class T>
void foo(T&& arg)
{
}
```

Now I need to call `foo` with a copy of my object:

```cpp
MyType object;
foo(object);
```

As written above, I will have a call on `void foo(MyType& arg)`, but **I don't want to pass a reference to my object**. I also want to avoid moving from my object in order to trigger deduction of `void foo(MyType&& arg)`.

What I want to do is **create a copy of `object` at the call site of `foo`**:

```cpp
foo(copy(object));
```

I have tried the following things:

- Creating a `copy` function myself, to generate objects: `template <class T> T copy(T arg) { return arg; }`
- Copy by means of forward casting: `foo(std::forward<MyObject>(object))`, but don't think it works in generic code
- Explicitly copying by creating a local variable to pass to foo: `MyType copy(object); foo(std::move(copy));`

Is there a standard library facility or a "generally accepted" way to do this?

---

**EDIT**:

As mentioned in the comments, `foo(MyType(object))` is always a solution. I'm asking whether there is an idiomatic way because **in general spelling out the type in this case can be less safe**:

```
// Converting constructors may create spurious problems:
foo(AnotherType(object)); 
// This can compile even if decltype(object) != AnotherType
```

whereas a solution that requires no attention in specifying the type is always safe:

```
foo(copy(object));
```

Comment: `foo(MyType(object))` doesn’t work for some reason?

Comment: What the problem with `void foo( T(reference) );` ?

Comment: @KonradRudolph @VictorGubin  I expected some dedicated syntax like `foo(+object)` for some reason or a library facility like `std::as_const` but for copies. Maybe in the copy case there's no need for something else

Comment: @KonradRudolph But added an edit on why I may want to avoid explicitly spelling out the type . I mean I'm totally cool with `foo(auto(object))` if it does the correct thing

Comment: @LorahAttkins That’s a good point, yes. You can always use `decltype(object)` in place of `MyType` but that’s replicating the object name. If you want to avoid that, prior to C++23 with `auto`, you’ll have to write your own copy function. At any rate, keep in mind that a copy constructor call may *always* be elided by a conforming compiler. You simply **cannot** rely on an actual copy being made.

Comment: IMO this question suffers form [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please explain WHY do you have such requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a *decay-copy* function yourself:

```
template <class T> 
constexpr std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v)
{ return std::forward<T>(v); }
```

then

```
foo(decay_copy(object));
```

It's worth noting that you can also use `auto(x)` to get language-supported *decay-copy* in C++23:

```
foo(auto(object));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bPe8YvEd1)

See [P0849](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0849r8.html) for more details on `auto(x)`.

Comment: I can’t think of a situation where `std::forward` is needed here, and where it does anything different than just `return v;`. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This allows *decoy_copy* to sometimes just *move* objects if `decay_copy(std::move(object))`.